# Is this sentence wrong or right? why? "I am going to school by bus everyday"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

We have this conversations here at our office about this sentence.

"I am going to school by bus everyday"

I said that this sentence is right and nothing is wrong about it.

but my friends says that it's completely wrong. because when you have everyday at the end you cannot have "going" and the right sentence is 
"I go to school by bus everyday" ( which is also right in my opinion )

Comment: both are right, but they mean slightly different things.

Comment: thank you for your response. can you explain more please. what is that slight difference ?

Comment: they are both answers to questions, and they sound like different answers to different questions. the 2nd could be 'how do you get to school?', the 1st 'how did having to sell your car affect you?'

Comment: @JonMarkPerry what do you think about that another answer ? http://english.stackexchange.com/a/372563/219243

Comment: it's okay, another thought, the 1st sounds like you are talking to someone you know, the 2nd to a stranger

Comment: What is the focus of the sentence?  Is it that you go to school, and the method of transportation is supplemental information, or is your point that you take the bus, and where you take it is supplemental information?  Or is the daily schedule the point?  Burying "by bus" in the middle makes it the least important element, if that's your intention.  Sticking "everyday" in the middle would make that the least important.  If the schedule is the key: Everyday, I go to school by bus.  If the transportation is key: I take the bus to school everyday.

Comment: @fixer1234 So you think the sentence "I am going to school by bus everyday" is right or wrong ?

Comment: Chris M's answer correctly addresses that.  "I am going to school by bus everyday" is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

The present continuos tense 'I am going' describes an action that is either occurring or about to occur but which will soon cease. So, 'I am going to school by bus' implies that soon I will no longer be going to school by bus.
'Every day' gives no such sense of cessation and so should be used with the simple present tense.

Comment: Im sorry but I cannot understand what your saying. be more specific about it and just answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: You can only use the phrase 'I am going to school by bus everyday' if it is qualified by another statement such as 'until I buy a car' which denotes that at some time the action of going to school by bus will stop happening.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong in almost every particular. The present continuous form in general represents an ongoing action that may be continue into the future, but it has no sense of proximate cessation. If I say, "I am breathing easily" (perhaps after using an inhaler), do you think this means that I'm not breathing now but will soon start? Or that I'll stop soon after I start? *Going* is a special case of future reference with an infinitive: *I am going **to attend** school* means that the attendance is in the future. But there's still no implication of cessation.

Comment: If you say I am breathing easily it implies that you are doing so right now but may not have done so in the recent past and may not do so at some point in the future. Only 'I breathe easily' implies that this is something which you always do. If I were to say 'I am walking up a hill' would that imply to you that I am continuously walking up a hill. It implies to me that walking up a hill is what I am doing right now but that I expect to be no longer walking up a hill at some point in the future.  'I walk up hills' states that this is what I do on a regular basis and for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

"I am going to school by bus everyday" is grammatically not correct.

"Present continuous/progressive tense is used to talk about temporary actions and situations that are going on 'around now':before, during and after the moment of speaking. We often use simple present tense to talk about permanent situations, or about things that happen regularly, repeatedly or all the time".(Practical English Usage-by Michael Swan)

Simple Present Tense is used in general statements of what was true in past time, is true now, and is likely to be true in future time-**all-inclusive time.**

*I go to school everyday by bus*. means: bus is my means of conveyance to go to school(yesterday, today, and tomorrow).

*How does he earn his living? - He **sells** books*. The Simple Present Tense  verb **sells** means that he sold books yesterday, he is selling books now, and he will sell books in the future.